How to smooth out noise of a mesh eigenvector?
I have computed the eigenvectors of the cotan Laplacian of a mesh. It looks like this:

I used ARPACK to get the output, as you can see, there's some lo level noise. What technique could I use to smooth things out?

What are you showing us in the image? I am not sure I am seeing the noise. I think that you can apply a Gaussian filter over your mesh.

The image is is the visualization of the fiedler eigenvector of the mesh laplacian. There's a lot of low level scalar differences. I would expect the color gradient to be much smoother than shown here.

A quick and dirty $O(n)$ solution would be to replace the value at each node with the average value of its neighbors

Do you have the same problem if you visualize the Fiedler eigenvector of a simpler mesh, a sphere, for example?
